# Plot linear regression from list of DataFrames

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to plot a linear regression of the below data and having trouble with sklearn's `LinearRegression.fit()` function which shows this error: `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:`. I am unsure on how to go about this and have researched a lot on this forum on how to plot a regression and extract the dataframe from the list to analyze and plot. I tried to convert to np.reshape and convert to array to no avail. It won't even fit (X, Y[0]).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


colors = ['r','g','b','k', 'y', 'c', 'orange', 'm', 'darkviolet', 'lawngreen', 'firebrick']
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=False)

# replace all instances of 'x' with blank
dataset = dataset.replace(to_replace='x', value='NaN') 

# get X, which is 1-10 in this case
X = dataset.iloc[:,0] 

# length of set X
lenX = float(len(X)) 

def get_Y(dataset, iterations):
    '''
    gets Y and the mean of each set of Y
    '''
    Y_list, Y_mean = [], []
    i = 1

    while i<(iterations+1): 
        Y = dataset.iloc[:,i]
        Y = pd.to_numeric(Y, errors='coerce') # change object dataframe to float64
        Y_list.append(Y) 
        Y_mean.append(Y.mean()) # get mean
        i += 1
    return Y_list, Y_mean

Y, Y_mean = get_Y(dataset, lenX)

# plotting all 10 lines
for i in range(len(X)):
    plt.plot(X, Y[i], colors[i])

#newY = np.reshape(Y,100)
#newX = np.reshape(X,10)

LinearRegression().fit(newX,newY)
#reg.score(X,Y)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

This is in data.csv:

```
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,3.5,3.4,3.0,3.6,3.5,3.1,3.2,3.5,3.0,3.5
2,2.9,2.6,2.9,2.7,2.5,2.6,2.9,3.1,2.6,3.0
3,2.3,2.5,2.3,2.0,2.7,2.7,2.4,2.5,2.8,2.3
4,2.1,2.4,2.3,2.4,2.6,2.1,2.0,2.6,2.2,2.2
5,2.2,1.9,2.0,2.3,2.1,2.0,2.1,1.8,1.9,1.8
6,1.9,2.0,2.1,2.2,1.8,2.3,2.2,1.8,2.1,1.7
7,1.9,2.1,2.1,2.3,1.9,2.3,2.1,2.0,2.2,2.0
8,x,2.2,2.1,2.3,1.9,2.3,2.1,2.9,x,2.1
9,x,1.9,x,2.2,x,2.2,1.9,x,x,1.8
10,x,1.9,x,2.1,x,x,2.1,x,x,2.0
```

[image: Plot without regression.]

Comment: What is your feature and target columns? usually the last columns is target, all previous ones are feature. I'm also guessing your given csv's first row and first columns is just for indexing i.e. not part of real dataset. If that's the case, I believe a solution won't be hard

Comment: @ShihabShahriar Thanks for your response. All are feature columns. The first column is my X-axis set, first row is indexing.

Comment: @ShihabShahriar Alternative solution I'm working on that is easier than dealing with the several DataFrames in a list: I found the mean for each row via `dataset.iloc[i-1, 1:]`in `get_Y` 's while loop. I will now graph this with the X-axis and then find the linear regression of that. This eliminates any errors graphing DataFrame and looping it.

Comment: @ShihabShahriar I managed to successfully plot my line, finally :)